# How do I create a nested list in Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, repeater

I was wondering what is the best way to display a list "child" within another list "parent" in Web Forms. I'm trying make a dynamic menu, which can be edited (I have Lists of items which are parent and child in database). I was between a `Gridview` or `Repeater`, however here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="Admin/Admin.aspx">Admin</a></li>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>

<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">CORPORATE</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="conduct_and_ethics.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>conduct and ethics</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="vision_and_core_values.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>Vision and Core Values</a></li>
        <li><a href="technology_and_quality.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>Technology and Quality</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>Global Reach</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see there are 2 `ul` tags. One is parent and one is child, so I was thinking to put the first one in a `Gridview`, and its child in a `Repeater` or a `Gridview` again, however it looks to be challenging. Do you have any better ideas?

Here is my Lists In BLL:

```
public static List<CategoryBL> GetCategoryItem()
{
    using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
    {
        var query = from row in db.TblCategories
                    select new CategoryBL
                    {
                        Title = row.Title,
                        Description = row.Description,
                        Link = row.Link
                    };
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

And of course Sub Categories for a second `ul` tag, which is going to be showed in their `li` tags:

```
public static List<SubCategoryBL> GetSubCategories()
{
    using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
    {
        var query = from row in db.TblSubCategories
                    select new SubCategoryBL
                    {
                        Title = row.Title,
                        Description = row.Description,
                        PageLink = row.PageLink,
                        SubCategoryID = row.SubID
                    };
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

These are going to be bound with the controls, but which ones?

Comment: As i said. i am trying to make a dynamic menu by ASP.NET, however i don't know which control should i use Gridview or Reapter, because its Nested within each other.

Comment: Right, edited :) ty

Comment: In general, GridView should only be used for when you want to display tabular data. Repeater gives you much tighter control over the generated HTML. However, It's not clear that you need to use either. Those are meant for binding data to. I don't see that you have any data here to bind. It looks like a static menu.

Comment: @mason there are methods in my BLL which return a list, i have included them in the Question, would you be a dear and look them over?

Comment: Seems like a Repeater would do this pretty well. Why don't you try and implement this and see if you like it?

Comment: surething let me try then, do you have any example of Repeaters within the repeaters?

Comment: I'm sure Google or Bing or Yahoo or DuckDuckGo or whatever your search engine of choice has plenty of examples.

Comment: xD yepp thank you!